# Assigning bots to Excel Files

Tags: ruby, excel

I have found a pretty cool link describing how to write a program in ruby that scrapes a website for the weather. However I am having trouble trying to figure out how to make the program parse specified information from a a site and then input that information into an specified cell/s into an excel file. For example if the weather was going to be 'rainy' on Monday and 'sunny' on tuesday how would I get the program to enter 'rainy' and 'sunny' into cell A1:A2 respectively into an excel file? 
code:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'watir'
 require 'nokogiri'

 #start the browser up
 Watir::Browser.default = "firefox"
 browser = Watir::Browser.start  "http://www.weather.com/"

 browser.text_field(:id, "whatwhereForm2").set("san diego, ca")

 browser.button(:src,"http://i.imwx.com/web/common/searchbutton.gif").click

 browser.link(:text, "10-Day").click

 #pass in current page's html to nokogiri for parsing
 page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)

 puts page_html.xpath(".//*[@id='tenDay']/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/p").inner_text}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ctreate a spreadsheet by generating a CSV (comma separated value) file which can be then easily loaded into excel.

You can just do that by emitting lines yourself e.g.:

```
puts "#{value1},#{value2}"
```

Or you can use the CSV library, e.g.:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
end
```